# Has Turkey made any demands for the EU to meet so they keep the refugees?

Tags: european-union, turkey, refugees

### Brief context

Now lately, I have been watching the news, and [the President of Turkey had a meeting in Brussels](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/en/press/press-releases/2020/03/08/media-advisory-eu-turkey-leaders-meeting-brussels-9-march-2020/) to negotiate further conditions with the NATO and EU.

### European Countries Stances...

As far as I am concerned, the negotiation has been intense, and neither side has agreed on any conditions. In the most recent meeting, the EU has announced that they will receive the immigrants that have "successfully" and "illegally" crossed the border of Turkey to Greece.

Has Turkey made any demands for the EU to meet so they keep the refugees?

Comment: Related: A rather popular generic negotiation tactic is to never make the first offer.

Comment: I believe you are misunderstanding the EU position, especially WRT the immigrants in Greece. There are talks about taking a few thousand out of the Greek camps, not all of them. Mostly sick children. Other migrants who manage to cross the sea or break through the border would still be stuck in overcrowded camps in Greece.